# moderncv: add post script to cover letter

Tags: moderncv

I am currently writing a cover letter for a german company and I need to add a post script after the closing and before the enclosure of the letter (i.e. after my signature and before the line were I list my study certificates, see the example code below). Is there already a command like \ps or is there a way to define a new command to that purpose?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\name{Hans}{im Glück}
\title{M.Sc.}                               
\address{Glücksstr. 13}{55444 Glücksdorf}{Deutschland \medskip} 
\phone[mobile]{+49~(176)~111~2222}                    
\email{hglueck@bsp.de}                               


\begin{document}

\recipient{Max Mustermann AG}{Personalwesen \\ Hans-Beispiel-Straße 2 \\    55555 Beispielhausen}

\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Your sincerely, \vspace{0,3cm} \\
%\includegraphics[width = 4.5cm]{signature.png} \vspace{-1,0cm}}
\enclosure[Attachment]{study certifcates}          
\makelettertitle

text...

\bigskip


\makeletterclosing




\end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I think we will be better equipped to help you if you can provide a minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @Troy ok I have added example code

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the answer myself. You have to edit the moderncv.cls and the moderncvbodyi.sty files: add a new command e.g.

```
\newcommand*{\postscript}[1]{\def\@postscript{#1}}
```

in the letter design commands definitions section of the moderncv.cls file

and then add the line

```
   {\@postscript\\[3em]}%
```

before the line

```
{\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}%
```

in the moderncvbodi.sty files, in the letter style definition section (there are five such files:  moderncvbodi.sty ,..., moderncvbodv.sty, just add the line to each of the files)